# Entity Framework "Migrations Configuration" and autofac

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, autofac

I am trying to inject dependencies into the Entity Framework Configurations class and I cannot seem to get it to work. The configurations class looks like this-

```
public class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<ApplicationContext>
{
    private readonly IApplicationUserManager _applicationUserManager;
    public Configuration(IApplicationUserManager userManager)
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
        _applicationUserManager = userManager;
    }
    protected override void Seed(ApplicationContext context) {
      //seed data here
    }
}
```

And I am registering with Autofac like this-

```
  builder.Register(c => new Configuration(c.Resolve<ApplicationUserManager>()));
```

This will not work because running "Update-database" complains that "No migrations configuration type was found in the assembly". So obviously it doesn't like the parameter-less constructor. So I tried using property injection like this-

```
 public class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<ApplicationContext>
{
    public IApplicationUserManager ApplicationUserManager {get;set;}
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;

    }
    protected override void Seed(ApplicationContext context) {
      //seed data here
    }
}
```

and registering it with Autofac like this -

```
builder.Register(c => new Configuration { ApplicationUserManager = c.Resolve<ApplicationUserManager>() });
```

However, this doesn't work either, the ApplicationUserManager property is always null. Is it possible to inject properties into the Configuration class?

Comment: Just curious, why you need the IApplicationUserManager in the Configuration? Typically you want to keep this clean and run the UpdateDatabase where the configuration file resides?

Comment: @Spock it realize is a little strange, however Seeding complex user accounts with roles etc. is made significantly easier when I can use the rolemanager and usermanager abstractions. They are not totally necessary, since I can access the context directly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it looks really strange that you wanna use some dependency in migration configuration class. So I advice you to think about aproach in general.

**Explanation:**

Your configuration is correct, but when you use dependency injection you should keep in mind 2 things:

1. you should register your dependency in dependency container.
2. you should create component that contains dependency using your dependency container, so this container will inject all dependencies during creation of an object.

So you registered your dependency, but the problem is that instance of configuration class is creating not through dependency container. If you will create instance through dependency container e.g.

```
DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<Configuration>();
```

your injection will work. In your situation it is not acceptable, because configuration is creating by EF.

**Possible solution:**
You can try to resolve instance manually in your configuration class.

```
public class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<ApplicationContext>
{
    public Configuration(IApplicationUserManager userManager)
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
    }
    protected override void Seed(ApplicationContext context) {
       var applicationUserManager = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IApplicationUserManager>();
    }
}
```

**Conclusion:** think about your aproach first and if you really need to do this use proposed workaround.

Comment: Thanks I will take a look at this. As I mentioned in my comment to Spock, I don't really need to use the UserManager and RoleManager abstractions in the database migrations class, but they are a nicer than seeding complex objects manually.

Comment: I am marking this as the answer, since I went this route. I just used the context directly.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can even use your User/Role/Claim Classes without using Dependency injection and simply creating objects in the Configuration class. This works for me, with Identity Framework.

```
    UserClaimService userClaimService = new UserClaimService(new EfRepository<UserClaim>(context));
    UserRoleService userRoleService = new UserRoleService(new EfRepository<UserRole>(context));
    UserLoginService userLoginService = new UserLoginService(new EfRepository<UserLogin>(context));
    RoleService roleService = new RoleService(new EfRepository<Role>(context));

    ApplicationUserService applicationUserService = new ApplicationUserService(
            new EfRepository<ApplicationUser>(context),
            userRoleService,
            roleService);

    UserManager<ApplicationUser, int> userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser, int>(new UserStore(applicationUserService, userClaimService, userRoleService, userLoginService, roleService));
```